# When using Windows 8.1 Assigned Access with Google Chrome, how can I avoid the "Google Chrome didn't shut down correctly" message?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

I'm setting up a Windows 8.1 user with Assigned Access to Google Chrome. It seems to work well, however I haven't found a way for the user to avoid seeing the error  "Google Chrome didn't shut down correctly" after each reboot.

I'm guessing this is because the Assigned Access user cannot actually sign out, however it happens even if the browser window is closed before reboot. Does anyone have a suggestion about how to avoid this?